# scrollTop not work when focus is display on search text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can you please tell me why my **scrollTop** , which is inserted in aminated function.Actually I searching a text and focus should go search text.But it not scroll to match word ?

here is my fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/3MVNj/6/

```
function searchNext() {
   var searchTerm = $('.searchbox').val();
   if (searchTerm == '') {
       PG_alert("Please Insert Text.")
       return;
   }
   if (searchTerm == 'b' || searchTerm == 'r' || searchTerm == 'br') {
       // PG_alert("Please .")
       return;
   }

   if (searchIndex != -1) {
       searchIndex++;
       if (searchIndex >= $('.match').length) {




           //naveen end
           searchIndex = -1;
       }
       $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
       $('.match').eq(searchIndex).addClass('highlighted');
       $('#fullContainer').animate({
           scrollTop: $('.match').eq(searchIndex).get(0).offsetTop
       });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to provide the height for the `#fullContainer` element and give `overflow:scroll`

```
#fullContainer {
    height:500px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

Please see updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YQs6p/

Comment: 1) focus goes up 2) It is not going all match .please check "court".It will not search of child divs

Comment: For focus going up, you need to subtract 120, since the fillContainer is 120px down from the top of the window

Comment: `scrollTop: $('.match').eq(searchIndex).get(0).offsetTop - 120`

Comment: But it is not going all matches..because the class inside the pre and current div

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49870/discussion-between-user1542984-and-sajithnair)